# Cell for row at indexpath only called once

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am parsing a json data and in that one of the field is an array if it has a content.But if it has no content it is simply a string "No result."
I am using the following code to parse it :

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated


{
[super viewWillAppear:YES];
//URL is called.
if ([status isEqualToString:@"success"])

{
                if ([[[json objectForKey:@"Items"] objectForKey:@"item_list"] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])



                {
                    _Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0"];
                    ItemsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                }
                else
                {
                    ItemsArray = [[json objectForKey:@"Items"] objectForKey:@"item_list"];
                    NSLog(@"%d",[ItemsArray count]);
                    float Amount = 0;
                    NSLog(@"%d",[ItemsArray count]);
                    if ([ItemsArray count]>0)
                    {
                        for (int i=0; i<[ItemsArray count]; i++)
                        {
                            NSMutableDictionary * temp3 = [ItemsArray objectAtIndex: i];
                            NSString * x = [temp3 objectForKey:@"final"];
                            Amount = Amount + [x floatValue];
                        }
                        Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",BidAmount];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0"];
                    }
                }



                [TableViewOutlet reloadData];
```

}

This works fine.

When the field returns string i face no problem.But when the field is an array,I am stuck.
After running the project for the first time it works fine even if the array count is more than 0.But from second time onwards the Cellforrowatindexpath method is not called even when array count is more than 0....
These are my codes:

```
-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
NSLog(@"%d",[ItemsArray count]);
return  [ItemsArray count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableViewCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell==nil)
{
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.025];
NSDictionary *temp = [ItemsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UILabel *ItemName = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1000];
ItemName.text = [temp objectForKey:@"title"];

UILabel *Cost = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1001];
Cost.text = [temp objectForKey:@"final"];

return cell;

}
```

Someone please help me

Comment: Check the count of the ' ItemsArray '

Comment: Array has got contents..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you have not retained your ItemArray.

```
NSArray* array = [[json objectForKey:@"Items"] objectForKey:@"item_list"];
ItemsArray = [NSMutableArray alloc]]initWithArray:array];
```

Use this code snippet..hope it will work.

Comment: Sorry guys,,,,,It worked when I combined both the lines.Thank you very much